# Linux Mint - Cairo Dock freezes when removing an item

Tags: linux-mint, dock

I have installed Cairo Dock on Linux Mint which works great except when I go to remove an item from the dock it freezes.

This is because I haven't confirmed the removal of the button from the dialog box. as per this page - http://glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=6145

The problem is 90% of the time I have absolutely no idea where this dialog box is. Sometimes (rarely) it will show on top of all my open applications and I click "Yes" and we go happily on our way, but usually it won't show, and minimizing all applications doesn't reveal it. I've even tried removing an item from the dock with no applications open at all and the dialog box won't show even on top of the desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some details, please. What video card/driver? amd64 or i386? What WM/DE? With or without an xorg.conf?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this exact same issue by adding this line to /etc/apt/sources-list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

(Note: I'm running an older version of Linux Mint - change "precise" in the 
above line to match your system.)

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It turned out this did not go smoothly so I had to uninstall all the `cairo-dock` packages first and then install them all.

Now it just works.

Answer (score 1):

I am using mint 13 (maya) MATE edition and used to have the same problem.

Here is how I fixed it:

Use the `-W` or `--metacity-workaround` to start cairo-dock:

```
cairo-dock -W
```

Note this flag is only available with cairo-dock version 3.3. 
I think Mint 13 LTS has version 3.0 of cairo-dock which does not have that option.

Install cairo from the ppa, instructions here:
http://glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=6520